# how to use update as inner subquery in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to use **update as a inner subquery** in postgresql?

```
update unit_has_jobcard 
    set status = 'approval' 
where id = (update jobcard_has_approvals 
                      set approve = true 
            where id = 27 
            returning id);
```

I need to update two tables in single query. `addBatch` helps multiple queries hit a table in single time. But i need to know if is this possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a common table expression to update two tables in a single statement:

```
with approvals as (
  update jobcard_has_approvals 
     set approve = true 
  where id = 27 
  returning id  
)
update unit_has_jobcard
  set status = 'approval' 
where id = (select id from approvals);
```